# Issue with email rendering text in Outlook 365

Tags: email, html-email, office365

I'm having an issue with text in Office365 pushing some table cells about.

This is the only email client it's happening in and it's happening in all browsers.

It must be something to do with Office365 modifying the HTML.

[image]

The text has zero padding and margin, as do all the tds, tr, and table. All of the border collapses are correct too.

There's no whitespace between that tags.

The line-height is 1.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide the source code for your email? I'd like to help.

Comment: How are we supposed to help when you give us no code?

Answer (score 1):

Your Office365 uses the Microsoft Word rendering engine (what a headache!).
Other email clients uses the rendering engine from Firefox or IE for example.

Probably you have to change your HTML Code according to these rules:

1. You shouldn't use CSS positioning such as "float", "margin" and "padding".

   - Nested tables are your friend
2. In newer versions of Office you shouldn't use "display:block"
3. Every table cell previewed in Outlook 2013 contains a line height defined by Outlook. Therefore empty table cells display a minimum height of 15 pixels regardless of what the cell’s height attribute is set to. This can cause white gaps between images in your email.

Please post your code next time.